# eb deploy ERROR: TypeError - cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Sorry I don't see this question anywhere. I've deployed an environment for my application "scones" on AWS. It's fairly simple Node.js express app. Honestly it's just to test the elastic beanstalk deployment. Anyhoo I'm using ebcli and I've already done an "eb create scones1" and it does create the environment and launches it. But when I make some changes (not committed to git) and type 'eb deploy' on the command line I receive `ERROR: TypeError - cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects` every time. Even if I enter the environment name. Doesn't matter. What is happening? None of the documentation seems to mention any error like this. Is there an issue with my Python version? I

Comment: Also I thought it was a Python issue - was using Python 2 upgraded to Python 3 and reinstalled awsebcli and it still has the same issue. Now using EB CLI 3.14.6 (Python 3.4.3)

Answer (score 13):

I was having this same issue and determined it to be coming from the following line in ebcli/operations/deployops.py:

`io.log_info('Deploying code to ' + env_name + " in region " + region_name)`

I resolved it by explicitly specifying a region with `-r REGION` when executing the deploy. I imagine somewhere the default region should be configured so this does not happen.

Edit: I was able to permanently set the region with `eb init --region us-east-1`

Comment: The error I was getting was `ERROR: TypeError - must be str, not NoneType`. This answer helped me. I'd marked it as accepted @anthonyGalligani

Comment: You can probably also edit `.elasticbeanstalk\config.yml` and set `global:default_region`. I believe mine was null before I ran the above command.

Comment: You saved me on a Sunday night! Thanks a ton @cody.

Answer (score 6):

Solve with a simple `eb init`, put my credentials, and just works.

Comment: Many thanks! But for curiosity, what does it change? Checking my `git status` no files were modified (including the .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml, it remains the same). Environment variables?

Comment: Thanks man! I had already initialized it.. I was cursing python

Answer (score 1):

Try `git add .` to stage your commits. Then, `eb deploy --staged`. You can check out the --staged flag here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html

Comment: Not if you want to deploy an artifact built by Maven in `target/*-SNAPTSHOT.war` which isn't in your source control. https://exampledriven.wordpress.com/2017/01/09/spring-boot-aws-elastic-beanstalk-example/